# Under which circumstances is "krom" ambiguous in practice?

Tags: word-usage, grammar

The word "krom" is well-known as being ambiguous. As I understand, there are some clues for differentiating the two:

- "krom" of addition (in addition to, besides):

  - sentence-initial or -final
  - Normally the sentence also contains "ankaŭ" (also), "ankoraŭ" (still), or "eĉ" (even).
  - synonyms (for disambiguation): "inkluzive de"
- "krom" of exception (except for, apart from):

  - usually sentence-final
  - The preceding statement normally contains a universal quantifier or negation.
  - synonyms (for disambiguation): "kun escepto de", "escepte de", "escept(int)e ", "ekskluzive de"

**In which circumstances do genuinely ambiguous uses of "krom" occur?** Can one characterize those circumstances? If my notes above are correct (and please tell me if they are not), instances of "krom" that are

- sentence-final;
- in a sentence without: ankaŭ, "ankoraŭ", "eĉ"; and
- in a sentence without a universal quantifier or negation

are most likely to lead to genuinely confusing sentences.

**What are some realistic (non-artificial) examples of ambiguous sentences with "krom", ideally taken or adapted from real-life writing?**

I should note that one of the sources for my notes is [section 12.3.6 ("Anstataŭ and krom") of the grammar](https://lernu.net/gramatiko/anstatau_kaj_krom) on [lernu!](https://lernu.net/). (This grammar is itself a condensed translation of PMEG.) That is, I am aware of the discussion of this issue in PMEG, but would like a characterization of circumstances or list of realistically occurring examples in which it actually matters. In other words, as a language learner, I would like to know what cases I need to pay attention to in practice, either to avoid ambiguity in language production or to avoid misunderstanding in language comprehension.

Comment: Bonvolu legi [Risko de miskompreno (pri `krom`)](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/aliaj_rolvortetoj/krom.html#i-gto) en la Plena Manlibro de Esperanta Gramatiko.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eduardo Trápani already referred to a subchapter [*Risko de miskompreno*](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/aliaj_rolvortetoj/krom.html#i-gto) in PMEG. That subchapter states that normally there are other words making it clear or the context otherwise makes it clear which way *krom* is used.

My experience is that it is actually hard, especially in speech, to avoid adding *ankaŭ, ankoraŭ, eĉ* or a negation and thereby making a sentence ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see that your experience agrees with the sentiment in PMEG 2022, 12.3.6.3. Krom, "Risko de miskompreno": "Normale la kunteksto klare montras, ĉu temas pri escepta aŭ aldona *krom*. [...] Tiaj miskompreneblaj frazoj estas tre maloftaj[.]"